# What does this grep command actually do?

Tags: parsing, grep, geektool

I'm trying to get a hang of grep. I've got the following command from a GeekLet script that someone made for getting the weather info off some website:

```
curl -s 'http://thefuckingweather.com/?zipcode=61820' | grep '"content\|"remark\|span' || sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' | sed 's/]*>//g' | sed 's/&#176;/°/'
```

I'm not worried about the sed command right now. I know it clears up the output to be neatly formatted, but for now I'm just trying to figure out the grep command.

I have a couple of questions that none of the guides/manuals over there seem to have a clear answer for:

1. What does the backslash (`\`) do over here?
2. What do the pipes "|" in between do?
3. Why is "content\|" in double quotes?

Also any other ideas/guides that you know of which touch upon parsing html content with grep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What does the backslash (`\`) do over here?

   `grep` uses an "[escaped](http://steve-parker.org/sh/escape.shtml)" pipe (`|`) to mean logical OR.  In other words, `grep 'foo\|bar'` means print any lines that contain **either** "foo" **or** "bar".
2. What do the pipes "|" in between do?

   See answer to 1.
3. Why is "content\|" in double quotes?

   It is not. The quotes are part of the pattern being searched for, the output of the `curl` command you give contains these lines:

   ```
   </title><meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" /> 
   [...]  
   <div class="content">
   ```

   The quote (not quotes, the second `"` belongs to the next pattern, `"remark`) before the word "content" is there to make grep print only the second of the lines above. It is part of the actual search pattern: `"content`.

Comment: Thank you! That cleared it up. Also if someone else needs to know more about this I found a good grep resource here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/